# How to write maintainable JavaScript ala' Bash scripts with advanced reporting features?

Tags: javascript, linux, oop, system-administration

I would like to write a script to execute backup procedure for multiple computers in an office. How can I write in a way that I can granually control execution path and also is easy to read and modify? Do I need OOP and SOLID?

The script should make sure that a computer is alive, if not WoL it and leave it in initial state after backup.

Also, the script should do a couple of basic health checks such as `smartctl -H` and after that execute `rsync ...` and `brtbk ...` commands to do the actual backup.

I would like the script to produce a one page report sent to an email address with a clear title indicating wether I should investigate or I can ignore the email.

I already tried to write this in vanilla JS with async/await but failed because of a complex configuration JSON I came up with.

```
var task = {
    type: 'main',
    config: {
        host: '10.5.1.158',
        mac: 'e0:d5:5e:ee:de:3d',
    },
    task: {
        type: 'ensureAlive',
        task: [
            {
                type: 'smartCheck',
                dev: '/dev/sda'
            },
            {
                type: 'smartCheck',
                dev: '/dev/sdb'
            },
            {
                type: 'failEarly',
                task: [
                    {
                        type: 'rsync',
                        config: {
                            from: `root@{{config.ip}}:/home/VirtualBox\ VMs/a15:/backups/a15/vms/a15/`,
                            to: '/backups/a15/',
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'btrfsSnapshot',
                        config: {
                            dir: '/backups/a15/',
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

```
async function run(ctx, task) {
    if (!task) {
        return;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(task)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
            await run(ctx, task[i]);
        }
        return;
    }

    var config = Object.assign({}, ctx.config || {}, task.config || {});
    var f = ctx.getFunction(task.type);
    try {
        var result = await f(config);
        task.output = result;
    } catch (error) {
        task.output = Output({ isOk: false, errorMessage: error.message, errorStack: error.stack })
    }

    var newCtx = Object.assign({}, ctx, { config });
    await run(newCtx, task.task);
}
```

The recurring `run` function became too complex to understand and modify/add features.

I was expecting to get something as easy to read as this, no matter wether this is JSON or actual JavaScript. Pseudocode below:

```
async function a15(report) {
    var wasAlive = wakeUp();

    try {
        await smartCheck();
    } catch (error) {
        report.addError(error);
    }

    try {
        await smartCheck();
    } catch (error) {
        report.addError(error);
    }

    try {
        await rsync();
        await btrbk();
    } catch (error) {
        report.addError(error);
    }

    if (!wasAlive) {
        shutDown();
    }
}
```

**What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?**

For extra clarification I would like to attach additional config layouts I tried.

Another config try which happened to be too complex to program. Since this config is flat, the main difficulty is related to passing a variable indicating that host is alive (at `wakeUp`) to the end of the config (at `shutDown`).

```
var a15: TaskDescription[] = [
    {
        type: 'wakeUp',
        config: {
            host: '10.5.1.252',
            mac: 'e0:d5:5e:ee:de:3d'.replace(/:/g, ''),
            timeout: '5',
            user: 'root',
            privateKey: '/Users/epi/.ssh/id_rsa',
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'smartCheck',
        config: {
            dev: '/dev/sda',
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'smartCheck',
        config: {
            dev: '/dev/sdb',
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'command',
        configTemplateFromConfig: true,
        config: {
            command: 'rsync -a --inplace --delete -e ssh root@{{host}}:/home/santelab/VirtualBox\ VMs/a15:/mnt/samsung_m3/a15/ /backups/a15/'
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'command',
        config: {
            command: 'btrbk -c /mnt/samsung_m3/a15.conf run'
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'shutDown',
        runIf: 'wasAlive',
        config: {
            host: '10.5.1.252',
            mac: 'e0:d5:5e:ee:de:3d'.replace(/:/g, ''),
            timeout: '5',
            user: 'root',
            privateKey: '/Users/epi/.ssh/id_rsa',
        },
    },
];

export interface TaskDescription {
    type: string;
    config?: TaskConfig;
    configTemplateFromConfig?: boolean;
    ignoreError?: boolean;
    runIf?: string;
}

export type TaskConfig = {
    [key: string]: string,
}
```

Comment: "Is this even possible?" Sure, somehow it probably is.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made it.

There are 2 key concepts that are required:

1. never throw an error, always return a result that wraps error and value
2. use generators - yield magic

Here is a proof of concept for localhost writen in TypeScript. I could use JavaScript as well.

```
import { WakeUp, Config as WakeUpConfig, Result as WakeUpResult } from './WakeUp';
import { SmartCheck, Config as SmartCheckConfig } from './SmartCheck';
import { Command, Config as CommandConfig, Result as CommandResult } from './Command';
import * as I from './interfaces';

async function* localhost() {
    var wakeUpResult = (yield WakeUp({ host: 'localhost', mac: 'e0:d5:5e:ee:de:3d', timeout: 5, tries: 20 })) as WakeUpResult;
    if (wakeUpResult.error) { return; }

    var echoResult = (yield Command({ command: `echo test` })) as CommandResult;
    if (echoResult.error) { return; }

    if (!wakeUpResult.value) {
        yield Command({ command: 'echo shutdown' });
    }
}

(async function () {
    var iterator = localhost();

    var lastResult: IteratorResult<any> = { value: undefined, done: false };
    do {
        lastResult = await iterator.next(lastResult.value);
    } while (!lastResult.done);
})()
```

I think the core `localhost()` is easy to read and allows for easy modifications.